# JNI what types can I use instead of given (unsigned int, const char*, const wchar_t*, .... )

Tags: java, c++, android, java-native-interface

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) Users !

I am trying to covert some functions that I had written in c++ to java. Exactly I have a .so library witch I have written in c++ and now I must call functions from my Android application. Functions like this:

```
unsignd int Uninitialize();
---------------------------------------
unsignd int DeviceOpen(
    const wchar_t* deviceID,
    unsigned long* phDevice);
---------------------------------------
typedef struct BlobData_s {
     unsigned long     length;
     unsigned char     data[1];
} dsmBlobData_t;

unsignd int Enroll(
    unsigned long       hDevice,
    const char*         userID,
    BlobData_s*         pInputInfo,
    void*               pUserData);
```

Now how you can see I have functions and typedefs that I want to write in java style, but my problem is that there are no `unsigned int` java type ([link](http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/cs510ajp/index.html#Example)). I knew that instead of `int` I can use `jint`, instead of `char*` I can use `jchar*` but what I must do with

- `const wchar_t*`
- `unsigned long`
- `unsigned char`

What can I use instead of that types.

I try in this way

```
jint Java_com_example_testApp_TestApp_DeviceOpen( jchar* deviceID, int* phDevice)
{ 
      return DeviceOpen((const wchar_t*)deviceID, (unsigned long*)phDevice);
}
```

**Am I right ?***

Thanks in advance, ViToBrothers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you'll have to map your types to Java types.  As you say,
there is no `unsigned` in Java, and no `wchar_t`.  Once you've decided
what types to use on the Java side (e.g. `int` instead of `unsigned`, or
maybe `long`; and probably `java.lang.String` for both `char*` and
`wchar_t*`), you'll have to declare your native methods using them, and
implement the JNI in a way which maps them to your internal values.

Also, if your C++ code uses exceptions, you'll have to catch them and
remap them in the JNI interface.

For starters, I'd see if some existing tool, like swig, would do the
job.  If it didn't, I'd still use it to get example code, which can then
be copy/pasted and edited.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use `jchar*` as it not a valid type for Java.

I suggest you use javah to generate the Java header from a Java class with native methods.  This will show you the correct types to use. (I don't know what the equivalent for Android is)

In many cases there is no direct equivalents so you have to used methods to copy the data.

BTW: I wouldn't be so worried about unsigned vs signed as the number involved just store an id.  These are not values you can perform arithmetic operations on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry but can you tell me how can I use javah ? give an example or link of how to use it ? or where to read about it ?

Comment: Do you mean like these? http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javah+for+android+examples

Comment: No, This I can do myself. I have searched "javah for android examples" and "javah" and "how to use javah" but nothing helpful. may be you knew concrete article witch helps me ... Thanks a lot